# wrapping columns in the same line with inline-block or float left

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns which are equal width but sometimes I may have unequal width so I am using pixels not percents to define the width and all three columns I want in same line in any resolution but the last one goes below the line. Also the middle one has margin-left and right suppose equal to 32px.

```
  | first box according to this line            | last box according to this line
+-|---------------------------------------------|-+
| +-----------+   +------------+   +------------+ |
| |    312px  |   |  312px     |   |   312px    | | 
| +-----------+   +------------+   +------------+ |
+-|---------------------------------------------|-+
  +------wrapper width 1001 pixels--------------+
|                                                 |
+-----------outer width 1100 pixels---------------+
```

How to implement to get this? What method should I use for best practice `float or inline-block`?

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/REjtW/) Please read texts in JavaScript code console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Used to** `table` and `table-cell` properties **as like this**

```
.parent{width:1001px;display:table;}
.child{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;}
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X3jhV/)**

---

**Second Option is according** to `Mr. @Harshit Tailor`

```
.main{margin-top: 20px; width: 1001px;background:green; text-align:center;font-size:0;}
.incols{display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;text-align:left; width: 308px;font-size:14px; border: 2px solid red;
box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.two{margin: 0 32px;}
```

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/REjtW/1/)**

Comment: So this was causing not setting box-sizing? Thanks. And could I do as your First method but mid one should be like your demo2.

Answer (score 2):

use `inline-block`

```
div.demo
{
  display:inline-block;
 width:312px;
}
```

Comment: but it goes below the line? why?

Answer (score 0):

Have the child divs in one parent div, give the parent a width and give the parent divs widths as well that add up or are less in total than the parent and float them all left.

```
<style type="text/css">

.parent {

    width: 900px;
}

.child1, .child2, .child3 {

    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

</style>



<div class="parent">

<div class="child1">I am a child!</div>
<div class="child2">I am a child!</div>
<div class="child3">I am a child!</div>

</div>
```